# Why JAX-WS generates wrapper for all method arguments?

Tags: wsdl, jax-ws, cxf

I am trying to generate web service interface using jax-ws, but i am getting a methods with wrapper class for all arguments instead of arguments list. For example:

```java
@SOAPBinding(parameterStyle = SOAPBinding.ParameterStyle.BARE)
@WebResult(name = "ResendControlsToDmiResponse", targetNamespace = "http://tempuri.org/", partName = "parameters")
@WebMethod(operationName = "ResendControlsToDmi", action = "http://tempuri.org/ResendControlsToDmi")
@Generated(value = "org.apache.cxf.tools.wsdlto.WSDLToJava", date = "2014-01-30T16:01:26.266+02:00")
public ResendControlsToDmiResponse resendControlsToDmi(
@WebParam(partName = "parameters", name = "ResendControlsToDmiData", targetNamespace = "http://tempuri.org/")
    ResendControlsToDmiData parameters
);
```

Can't understand why it's happening and how to generate method with corredct signature.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There rules about the naming of the part elements as they related to the operation name.  In your case, it looks like the operation is named `resendControlsToDmi`, but the incoming data part/element is named `ResendControlsToDmiData`.   Remove the `Data` off the end of that and it may change.   The response element is properly `ResendControlsToDmiResponse`.

Comment: So, as i understand, input parameter name should match operation name?